# Force Take() to get less than count if there are no enough elements

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to get 3 or less elements (in case after the `Skip()` there aren't 3 elements to take).

Is it possible with linq syntax?

```
   myFilteredList = sortedFullList
      .Skip(skipCount)
      .Take(3);
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) does do that automatically.  Your code sample as given should work:

> Take enumerates source and yields elements until count
>   elements have been yielded or source contains no more elements.

Answer (score 16):

This should work as is with your query - `Take(3)` will return 3 elements *at most* - but less if there are less items in the enumeration.